# Why an ordered list isn't equal to list.sort()?

Tags: python

I have this code where I check if the list is ordered. So I used `array == array.sort()` to verify this condition. Where did I go wrong?

Code:

```
def isOrdered(t):
    """
    t: list
    return True if the list is ordered in a growing sense
    """
    array = t
    if array == array.sort(): #This doesn't work
        return True

    else:
        return False

print(isOrdered([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(isOrdered([1, 3, 2, 4, 2]))
```

Comment: Did you check what `list.sort` returns?

Comment: "None" :( I'm so stupid

Comment: `False` != `None`

Comment: Also, `.sort()` sorts *in place*, i.e. modifies the object, so `array` would always be equal to itself.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: even like this it doesn't work.

Comment: array = t
    array.sort()
    if array == t:
        return True

Comment: @TechMatt you should consider accepting an answer that helped you! cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should use `sorted` instead, as it returns a copy of the list that is sorted. You can also simplify your code a little bit, as comparison returns a boolean:

```
def isOrdered(t):
    """
    t: list
    return True if the list is ordered in a growing sense
    """
    return t == sorted(t)
```

Comment: Would return `True` for `print(isOrdered([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))`  but it shouldn't since *if the list is ordered in a growing sense*?

Comment: @DirtyBit: It's quite possible that the OP considers `[1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` to be ordered in a "growing sense" since they haven't precisely defined what that means—so this is the simplest answer to their question.

Comment: @martineau  Indeed. It could be :)

Comment: Hey, @TechMatt, how about some kind of response?

Answer (score 0):

`array.sort()`
works inline, meaning it doesn't return anything.

Instead, make a copy, sort the copy then check for similarity.

```
def isOrdered(t):
    """
    t: list
    return True if the list is ordered in a growing sense
    """
    t_copy = t[:]
    t_copy.sort()
    return t_copy == t
```

Comment: You will still reference the same list, not do a copy of it. It you would have a nested list, you would have to do a so called deep copy with ``t_copy = copy.deepcopy(t)`` after running ``import copy``

Answer (score 0):

**OP**: *return True if the list is ordered in a growing sense*

**Hence**:

```
def isOrdered(t):
    """
    t: list
    return True if the list is ordered in a growing sense
    """
    res = sorted(t)                # check if the lst is soreted    
    if res:   
        if len(t) == len(set(t)):  # ensure no duplicates in the lst
            return True
        else:
            return False           # duplicate means list is not in growing sense
    else:
        return False

print(isOrdered([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))     # Valid list with Growing sense
print(isOrdered([1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))  # Invalid list with dupes
print(isOrdered([1, 3, 2, 4, 2]))     # Invalid list not sorted
print(isOrdered([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1]))  # Invalid list with declining
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
True
False
False
False
```