# How can I print the result of a return statement near a print sentence on the console?

Tags: python

I have the necessity to print a sentence on the console and near the sentence the result of a return statement. This is an example:

```
print("Le stringhe sono vuote")
return None
```

This is a piece of code of a function.
This is outside the function:

```
print(function([...]))
```

This is the result:

https://ibb.co/wM1zWk5

How can I bypass the new line?

Comment: Perhaps consider accepting an answer on your previously asked question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55301060/why-an-ordered-list-isnt-equal-to-list-sort

Answer (score 5):

```
print("Le stringhe sono vuote", end = "")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on **Python 3.x**:

> By default python’s print() function ends with a newline. Python’s
>   print() function comes with a parameter called ‘end’. By default, the
>   value of this parameter is ‘\n’, i.e. the new line character. You can
>   end a print statement with any character/string using this parameter.

```
print("Le stringhe sono vuote", end="")
```

**Python 2.6.0a2 and later**:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("Le stringhe sono vuote", end="")
```

**OR**

Why not return a concatanated val:

```
return ("Le stringhe sono vuote", None)
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I bypass the new line?

You can pass `end=""` to `print()`:

```
print(function([...]), end="")
```